# Can you automatically open a form based off the last input record in MS Access?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I currently have 3 different forms in my access database that have to with specific dock locations based on size. I want to make it so that when a customer adds their information about their boat in one form (length and width of boat) it will automatically open the corresponding dock location form.

Example:
Say a customer adds information in a form that their boat is 25 feet long. Dock A Form only pertains to boats under 29 feet so I want that specific form to open when the customer adds that record

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Havent tried much. I tried to see if I can create a macro button that automatically open a form based off certain criteria but i dont know how to relate it to the record that was just added

Answer (score 0):

Use a select-case in the *OnClick* event of the button that opens the form:

```
Dim FormName As String

Select Case Me!BoatLength.Value
    Case < 29
        FormName = "SmallBoat"
    Case < 49
        FormName = "MediumBoat"
    Case Else
        FormName = "LargeBoat"
End Select

DoCmd.OpenForm FormName
```